# HTTP Status 500 - Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.StackOverflowError

Tags: java, gson, stack-overflow

I get the below exception after running my webportal for a while. I need to re login to eliminate this error. Because of this I am not able to run my development environment smoothly on eclipse.

This is my AuthenticationFilter.java

```
public class AuthenticationFilter implements Filter {
    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(AuthenticationFilter.class) ;
    static Map<String, String> permissionsMapping = new HashMap<String, String>();
    private static int domainOrGroupParentId = 0;
    static {
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {

        HttpServletRequest servletRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;

        if (servletRequest.getRequestURI().contains("onLoadOfLoginPage")
                || servletRequest.getRequestURI().contains("Corporate")
                || servletRequest.getRequestURI().contains("mainDashboard")
                // ||
                // servletRequest.getRequestURI().contains("mainDashboardWithoutDomainOrGroupParent")
                || servletRequest.getRequestURI().contains("loginButtonPressedForSuperAdminView")
                // ||
                // servletRequest.getRequestURI().contains("loginButtonPressedForNonSuperAdmin")
                || servletRequest.getRequestURI().contains("resources")
                || servletRequest.getRequestURI().contains("session")
                || servletRequest.getRequestURI().contains("forgot_password")
                || servletRequest.getRequestURI().contains("resetPassword")) {
>>Line52>>      chain.doFilter(request, response);

        } else {
            HttpSession session = servletRequest.getSession(false);
            try {
                if (null == session || SessionDataManager.getInstance().getLoggedInWebAdminUser().getWebAdminUserPojo()
                        .getUsername() == null) {
                    RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("onLoadOfLoginPage");
                    dispatcher.forward(request, response);
                    return;

                } else if (!servletRequest.getRequestURI().contains("get")) {

                    String username = (String) SessionDataManager.getInstance().getLoggedInWebAdminUser()
                            .getWebAdminUserPojo().getUsername();
                    String sessionID = session.getId();
                    domainOrGroupParentId = SessionDataManager.getInstance().getDomainIdFromRequest(servletRequest);
                    log.info("Attempting to maintain Session, with domainParent "+domainOrGroupParentId);
                    if (!WebAdminHelper.maintainSession(username, sessionID, domainOrGroupParentId)) {
                        RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("onLoadOfLoginPage");
                        dispatcher.forward(request, response);
                        return;
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {

            }
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig arg0) throws ServletException {

    }

}
```

Exception I get

```
type Exception report

message Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.StackOverflowError

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.StackOverflowError
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.triggerAfterCompletionWithError(DispatcherServlet.java:1276)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:958)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:870)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:852)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    net.codejava.spring.AuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationFilter.java:52)
root cause

java.lang.StackOverflowError
    com.google.gson.stream.JsonWriter.beforeName(JsonWriter.java:586)
    com.google.gson.stream.JsonWriter.writeDeferredName(JsonWriter.java:401)
    com.google.gson.stream.JsonWriter.value(JsonWriter.java:417)
    com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$13.write(TypeAdapters.java:362)
    com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$13.write(TypeAdapters.java:346)
    com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:68)
    com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:89)
    com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:195)
    com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:68)
    com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:89)
    com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:195)
    com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:68)
```

**EDIT**
I have identified the root causing line.

> response = new Gson().toJson(invException);

Type of

> InvalidObjectStateException invException

```
public class InvalidObjectStateException extends Exception {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -9086960433236073019L;
    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(InvalidObjectStateException.class);
    private String customErrorMessage = null;
    private Object exceptionCausingObject = null;

    public InvalidObjectStateException(String errorMessage, Object exceptionCausingObject) {
        super(errorMessage);
        this.customErrorMessage = errorMessage;
        log.info("InvalidObjectStateException : exceptionCausingObject"
                + ((exceptionCausingObject != null) ? exceptionCausingObject.getClass().toString() : ""));
        this.exceptionCausingObject = exceptionCausingObject;
    }

    public String getCustomErrorMessage() {
        return customErrorMessage;
    }

    public void setCustomErrorMessage(String customErrorMessage) {
        this.customErrorMessage = customErrorMessage;
    }

    public Object getExceptionCausingObject() {
        return exceptionCausingObject;
    }

    public void setExceptionCausingObject(Object exceptionCausingObject) {
        this.exceptionCausingObject = exceptionCausingObject;
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong here ? Why cant Gson parse the Exception ?

Comment: at line 52 you call doFilter from doFilter and at some point you run out of space for stack frames due to recursion.

Comment: Im calling chain.doFilter(2parameters) and my method is 3 parameters. Thats not the root cause.

Comment: you have `chain.doFilter(request, response);` after catch block and at line 52. Both of the statements have 2 params having same objects

Comment: What does your <filter-mapping> look like?

Answer (score 2):

I think this is not the right source of exception.  `net.codejava.spring.AuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationFilter.java:52)`. It just failed at this location due to low memory.

There should be another process/request which is converting a `response(maybe)/object to json string`. Look in the `response` object it should have a nested infinite object reference.

Comment: ok, yeah that sounds correct. the response object may have a circular reference.. i'll look into that and report back

Comment: I have found the root cause.. I wonder if that helps you answer itbetter

Comment: Not really! You need to find out the object type is in this Exception class - Object exceptionCausingObject. Maybe log the class name when the object is created.

Comment: I'm a little distressed seeing a `Logger` in the exception. Maybe the logger's implementation has a reference to the `InvalidObjectStateException`class (which has a reference to the logger) -> circular reference. An easy fix would be to alter the json serialization of the exception (maybe only marshall message & stacktrace)

Answer (score 2):

The problem in the `Object exceptionCausingObject`

It has circular references so Gson parser cannot parse it correctly and throws `StackOverflowError`

You can mark some fields of `exceptionCausingObject` classes as `transient`

```
private transient String name;
```

That will exclude them from Gson serialization.

Another option is to use `GraphAdapterBuilder`. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19204796/gson-deserialize-complex-object-with-recursive-dependencies)

Comment: I checked, at the time of the exception `exceptionCausingObject` was null.